# Linking Bootstrap to my VS Code project

Tags: visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I am going through VS Code for the first time and doing a bootstrap project. I used the marketplace to add bootstrap 4 and font awesome (install & reloaded) what else do I need to do?
As my project folder does not have and bootstrap files, but strangely the intellisense let's me use the bootstrap snippets. I ran the index.html and the page wasn't bootstrap styled. The download didn't add any files to my project. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed up some things. The extensions that you installed are more for quick coding of Bootstrap and for visualizing it better.

However Bootstrap is not installed on your site, which is a totally different process. You can achieve this in many ways. (npm, bower)

I would recommend you to read the Bootstrap getting started documentation.
(It's for Bootstrap 3 but it's the same principle)

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

Comment: the snippets were not so obvious, its weird that it does not drop the needed folders into the project. Thanks for your input.